# Adding a dynamic symbol name not work with AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED from configure.ac

Tags: c, autotools, autoconf

There is a macro to [add a new symbol into](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/autoconf.html#Defining-Symbols) the resulting config.h file from a configuration file. This allows you to check the system and enable options in C/C++ applications. There are two types of macros: adding a dynamic symbol and a fixed symbol. By using AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED, which is a macro to add a dynamic symbol, it is possible to set a symbol where the name or value is from a variable.

Here is my simple configure.ac file

```
name="test"
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([USE_${name}], [1], [Enable test usage])
```

I expecte that USE_test be added into config.h as C/C++ definistion. However, the difinistion does not exist in the result config.h file.

By running Autotools there is the following line in configure.status:

```sh
D["USE_test"]=" 1"
```

This means Autotools will search the config.h.in to replace the USE_test with the new value.

But the generated config.h.in file does not contain the following definition:

```
#define Use_test 1
```

So Autoheader does not run correctly?! And it is not possible to add a variable text as a symbol to config.h?!

Where is the problem or is it possible to add a symbol with a variable name by configure.ac?

Comment: I found your usage of the term "dynamic" a bit surprising in this context, but I can't say it's wrong.  To clarify for anyone else who trips over the same thing, I'm pretty sure you mean "dynamic symbol" in the sense of a C macro name that is determined at runtime by `configure`.  That is, the *name* is "dynamic", and that with respect to the `configure` script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the final config.h file does not contain the following definition
>   [...] config.h.in is generated dynamically and it does not contain the
>   definition too.

The latter is actually the key issue.  When you use `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` to request that definitions be recorded in a header file instead of being expressed via compiler command-line options, Autoconf handles it by processing one or more header templates, such as `config.h.in`, to produce the resulting header(s).  The `autoconf` command does not produce these templates itself, however.  You can write them by hand if you wish, but a separate program, `autoheader`, is available to perform this job, and `autoreconf` (not `autoconf`) automatically runs `autoheader` to generate a template for the first header named in the first `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` call.

The behavior you describe is a longtime known issue (not accounted a bug, *per se*), which you can find discussed [in the archives of the bug-autoconf mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-autoconf/2006-05/msg00090.html).  The resolution was a documentation change, whose result you can still see in [the section of the Autoconf manual that discusses Autoheader](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/autoheader-Invocation.html#autoheader-Invocation):

> In order to do its job, `autoheader` needs you to document all of the
>   symbols that you might use. Typically this is done via an `AC_DEFINE`
>   or `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED` call **whose first argument is a literal
>   symbol** and whose third argument describes the symbol (see Defining
>   Symbols).

(Emphasis added.)

This indeed seems to be the technically appropriate place for those details.  That is, `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED` does behave as advertised, as can be seen by disabling `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` (a viable workaround under many circumstances), or by employing one of the alternatives the docs go on to suggest:

> you can use `AH_TEMPLATE` (see Autoheader
>   Macros), or you can supply a suitable input file for a subsequent
>   configuration header file. Symbols defined by Autoconf's builtin tests
>   are already documented properly; you need to document only those that
>   you define yourself.

If you were to argue that it would have been nice for that issue to be mentioned in the `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED` docs, too, then I would fully agree with you.  But I do also think that the situation is considerably different now than when the doc change was first put in, on account of the introduction and rise to prevalence of `autoreconf`, which hides the involvement of `autoheader` from most users.

In any case, I'll ignore the "supply your own template" option, which is a bit fraught, and focus on `AH_TEMPLATE`.  To use it to support the particular case presented in the question, one would add something along these lines to `configure.ac`:

```
AH_TEMPLATE([USE_test], [Define to 1 to use test])
```

Perhaps you ask "What's the point then?  I might as well use a regular `AC_DEFINE`."  That's a good question, to which you should indeed give careful consideration.  Note well that there is no point to defining *arbitrary* preprocessor macros, as only those corresponding to symbols appearing in one or more of your sources will ever be expanded.  That does not necessarily make `configure`-time macro name generation useless, but it does mean that when maintaining `configure.ac`, you can and should have a complete list of all the generated macro names that need to be supported.  In that case, it is indeed plausible that you might write appropriate `AH_TEMPLATE` invocations for all the needed cases.  Under most circumstances, however, going straight to (conditional) `AC_DEFINE`s for each symbol is probably a better choice.

Comment: Thank you very much, Johan. Your clear response saves my time.